# Why do simple programs take up so much storage space?

Tags: c, compiler-construction

I created a simple hello world program in C like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Afterwards, I compiled it on Mac using gcc and dumped it using xxd. With 16 bytes per line (8 words), the compiled program was a total of 3073 lines or 49 424 bytes. Out of all these bytes, only 1 904 of them composed the program while the remaining 47 520 bytes were all zeros.
Considering that only approximately 3.9% of the bytes are not zeros, this is a clear example of a waste of space. Is there any way to optimize the size of the executable here? (By the way, I already tried using the `-Os` compiler option and got no results.)

Edit: I got these numbers by counting lines of hexdump, but within the lines containing actual instructions there were also zeros. I didn't count these bytes as they may be crucial to the execution of the program. (Like the null terminator for the string `Hello World!`) I only counted full blocks of zeros.

Comment: @Gerhardh sorry, I meant 16 bytes per line. 8 words. The size of the file also matches the 49 424 bytes.

Comment: What about only `#include <stdio.h>` ?

Comment: Executable files have a fixed structure that depends on the system. Unsure for gcc on Mac, but as the underlying system is Darwin which is a BSD derivative, I would assume elf. elf format is known to produce large files. But I can remember .com files on MS/DOS systems that were much more terse: a 256 bytes header,followed by raw machine code. The larger part of the executable was the standard library, but when using assembly, A *Hello world* program could be less that 300 bytes long...

Comment: so much bloat, so little time ...

Comment: https://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html walks through building a 45-byte executable.

Comment: I compiled with version 11 of Apple’s developer tools and got an executable size of 8656 bytes. Do you actually use a GCC that you installed separately from the Apple tools? (Apple’s tools install a `gcc` that actually executes `clang` so that old scripts continue working.) What version, and what switches did you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gcc on MacOS generates object and executable files in the [Mach-O](http://www.cilinder.be/docs/next/NeXTStep/3.3/nd/DevTools/14_MachO/MachO.htmld/index.html) file format.  The file is divided up into multiple segments, each of which has some alignment requirement to make loading more efficient (hence why you get all the zero padding). I took your code and built it on my Mac with gcc, gives me an executable size of 8432 bytes.  Yes, `xxd` gives me a bunch of zeros.  Here's the `objdump` output of the section headers:

```
$ objdump -section-headers hello

hello:  file format Mach-O 64-bit x86-64

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      Address          Type
  0 __text        0000002a 0000000100000f50 TEXT 
  1 __stubs       00000006 0000000100000f7a TEXT 
  2 __stub_helper 0000001a 0000000100000f80 TEXT 
  3 __cstring     0000000f 0000000100000f9a DATA 
  4 __unwind_info 00000048 0000000100000fac DATA 
  5 __nl_symbol_ptr 00000010 0000000100001000 DATA 
  6 __la_symbol_ptr 00000008 0000000100001010 DATA
```

`__text` contains the machine code of your program, `__cstring` contains the literal `"Hello World!\n"`, and there's a bunch of metadata associated with each section.

This kind of structure is obviously overkill for a simple program like yours, but simple programs like yours are not the norm.  Object and executable file formats have to be able to support dynamic loading, symbol relocation, and other things that require complex structures.  There's a minimum level of complexity (and thus size) for any compiled program.

So executable files for "small" programs are larger than you think they should be based on the source code, but realize there's a lot more than just your source code in there.

Answer (score 2):

The resulting file does not contain just the code and data needed by your program. It also contains metadata needed in order to properly load and execute the program. Generally speaking, this metadata may be split into multiple section, each section needing to be aligned at a certain boundary. In order to do this some zeroes may be added for padding. Doing the same checks on bigger programs will result in less of the space being taken by the metadata and the padding.

Answer (score 1):

The executable is probably also made to quickly load into memory. In particular text and data segments may be aligned to the page size of the OS. This is often 4KB or an even larger power of 2. Before you call something a waste of space, make sure you understand all the intricacies of link editing and loading, segments, and the [Executable and Linkable Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) (ELF).