# why executable file sizes is not same when compiled on different operating systems

Tags: c

I wrote program with c program,the executable file sizes is 8KB when compiled on ubuntu18.04,but if compiled the program on ubuntu20.04 ,the executable file sizes is 17KB.

Why is the gap so stark?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    
    int  main() {
      printf("hello world\n");
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You accidentally cited the same os and os version twice.

Comment: Who are you calling stark?

Comment: It's also highly likely the compiler is responsible for the difference, not the OS, and you haven't told us a thing about which compiler you're using, what version, and with what command line switches (in particular, the version often changes the default flags for the compiler, which is the most likely culprit here).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do simple programs take up so much storage space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66260709/why-do-simple-programs-take-up-so-much-storage-space)

Answer (score 1):

The size of the compiled program will depend on the compiler, compiler and linker options, libraries, startup code and executable file format.

It is very unlikely to be the same even if only one of the above differs.